# How can I remove authenticated users from Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I've working on a Firebase application and created a number of dummy yet authenticated users and data.  I like to wipe the hole thing clean and start over.  I can do this with the data but not the authenticated users.

In forge it says that if I delete my firebase I won't be able to create a new one with the same name. Though not the end of the world I find this mildly irritating.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Are you using Firebase Simple Login email / password authentication? If so, you can log into Forge and manually remove the users under the 'Auth' panel. For all other types of Firebase Simple Login authenticated users persist no user information, so there would be nothing to delete.

Comment: @RobDiMarco: can you post the same as an answer? That way Jack can accept it and it'll be easier to find for future takers.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't checked the tab under Authentication Providers/Email and Password.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firebase Simple Login email / password authentication,  you can log into Forge (at `https://<your-firebase.firebaseio.com`) and manually remove the users under the 'Auth' panel.

For all other authentication types in Firebase Simple Login (such as Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, Persona, etc.), no user data is persisted, and thus there is nothing to delete.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED as of Feb 12 2015.
its in the `https://<your-firebase.firebaseio.com?page=Auth`

at the bottom, you will see the Registered Users.
[image]