# Is there an API call for removing registered Firebase users?

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin, firebase-authentication

I know how to remove registered users manually via web interface (which is also answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156300/how-can-i-remove-authenticated-users-from-firebase)). This can be done without providing user's password.

Is there a way to remove a user automatically without their password? I have only found [removeUser](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/removeuser.html) API call which requires user's password.

It would help to simplify deployment for testing/stage environments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to programmatically access the email/password users in Firebase.

For development purposes, you can delete them through the [Login & Auth](https://puf.firebaseio.com/?page=Auth) tab of your app's dashboard.